# login from Realtime firebase database without authentication

Tags: javascript, typescript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angular8

Please help me to log in from the Realtime firebase database without authentication. I want to fetch key and compare the password to the user input password.

I have attached some code please review me.

loginComponent.html

```
<div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" id="empid" [(ngModel)]="empid" class="form-control m-2" placeholder="Employee Id">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group" *ngIf="!isForgotPassword">
                <input type="password" class="form-control m-2" [(ngModel)]="passwordInput" placeholder="Password" id="password">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group" *ngIf="!isForgotPassword">
            <span *ngIf="selectedVal == 'login'; else elseBlock">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-orange btn-block m-2" (click)="loginUser()">Login</button>
            </span>
```

loginComponent.ts

```
 emailInput: string;
 passwordInput: string;
 isForgotPassword: boolean;
 empId : string;
 userDetails: any;

constructor(
 private userService: UserService,
 private router: Router
) {
 this.selectedVal = 'login';
 this.isForgotPassword = false;
}

loginUser(){
  this.userService.login(this.empId, this.passwordInput);
}
```

UserService.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireDatabase} from 'angularfire2/database';
import { User } from '../user.model'
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import * as firebase from 'firebase';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
  })
 export class UserService {
  user : User[];
  ref = 'Batch'
  batch = 'DEC2019'

  constructor(
     public af: AngularFireDatabase,
     public router: Router
  ) { }

  login(empId: string, password: string){
     return this.af.database.ref('Users/').child(empId).once('value')
    .then(snapshot=>{ 

   })
   .catch(err =>{
     console.log('Something went wrong',err.message)
   })
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using angularfire, you can do the following in the service class:

```
items: Observable<any[]>;
...

 login(empId: string){
     return this.itemRef = db.object('item/' + empId).snapshotChanges();
 }
```

Then in the component, you can `subscribe` to the `observable`:

```
loginUser(){
  this.userService.login(this.empId).subscribe(action => {
  console.log(action.type);
  console.log(action.key)
  console.log(action.payload.val())
 });
}
```

`action.payload.val()` will contain your data, you can probably retrieve the password by doing `action.payload.val().password` if you have `password` as an attribute in the database. Then you can check if both the retrieved password is equal or not to the `passwordInput`. You should probably use `reactive-form` since you can easily do `validation` with it:

https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms#simple-form-validation

https://github.com/angular/angularfire/blob/master/docs/rtdb/objects.md